# how convert date into different format

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

hi frnds i got some data from api service it contains date also the date format is `2013-09-06T14:15:11.557`

which format it is??, how we can covert this date into `2013 sept 06 2:15`

i used these 2 methods for coverting them to my date format

```
public static Date stringToDate(String dateString)
    {
        Date date = null;
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT_WITHOUT_TIME);
        try {
            date = df.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }
```

and

```
public static String FormatDate(String dateString)
    {
        String s="";
        Date date = stringToDate(dateString);
        s = date.getDate()+" "+monthname[date.getMonth()+1]+" "+(date.getYear()+1900);
        return s;
        }
```

and this is my date format constant `public static final String DATE_FORMAT_WITHOUT_TIME = "yyyy-MM-dd";`
but it the parsing doesn't works correctly

Comment: and what are those "some errors"? can you post stacktrace?

Comment: what's your `Constants.DATE_FORMAT_WITHOUT_TIME`?

Comment: i added the date format constant

Comment: then that's the cause...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
    String date="2013-09-06T14:15:11.557";
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Date d=df.parse(date);
    df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm");
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

out put:

```
    2013-Sep-06 02:15
```

Comment: this one is right answer..

Answer (score 3):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");//Edit here depending on your requirements
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
String currentDateandTime1 = dateFormat.format(new Date());
Date dateObj = new Date();
dateObj = dateFormat.parse(stime);
Log.v("Hello", "" + dateFormat.format(dateObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Works like charm**

```
public static String FormatDate(String dateString) {

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            Date d = sd.parse(dateString);
            sd=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy' 'MMM' 'dd' 'hh:mm");
            System.out.println(sd.format(d));
            return sd.format(d);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return "";
    }
```